# search for a character in a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to check if a javascript string doesn't contain characters like (#,$,/,@) because it's a username. I have a tried this code :

```
for(i=0;i<usrlength;i++) {
    if ($username.charAt(i)=='#'||$username.charAt(i)=='$') {
    }
}
```

but it's too long

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Put all the special characters you want to exclude in a character set inside a regular expression:

```js
const verify = username => !/[#\$\/@]/.test(username);
console.log(verify('foo'));
console.log(verify('foo#'));
console.log(verify('foo!'));
console.log(verify('f$oo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to test the string with the desired pattern:

```js
var pattern = /[$#@/]+/;
var username = "prachi.user";
var hasInvalidChar = pattern.test(username);
if (hasInvalidChar) {
  alert("Case 1 - Invalid");
} else {
  alert("Case 1 - Valid");
}


var pattern = /[$#@/]+/;
var username = "prachi.user#$@#/";
var hasInvalidChar = pattern.test(username);
if (hasInvalidChar) {
  alert("Case 2 - Invalid");
} else {
  alert("Case 2 - Valid");
}
```